# EJB calls from grails to glassfish

Tags: grails, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.0

I need to use EJB remote calls from my grails application. For this in previouse Servlet application I used client glassfish jar(gf-client.jar) and is's worked.

How I can include gf-client.jar into build path in grails app for call EJB methodth?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was to copy all libraries of GlassFish application server to client mashine (directory with gf-client.jar and 2 levels up, check dependencies in gf-client.jar) and add only gf-client.jar to classpath of application. Ather dependencies will loaded automatically, when gf-client will loaded.

note 1: in my case for grails application witch I deploying to tomcat servlet container write full path to gf-client.jar to shared.loader section of catalina.properties file in conf dir, and restart tomcat.

note 2: for GlassFish v3.1 and up, replace gf-client.jar with gf-client-module.jar

Answer (score 0):

Put gf-client.jar into the lib directory of your grails app. Any jar files in the lib directory of your grails app will automatically be included when you run your application as well as be packaged in generated war files.

Comment: It's not so easy! 
At first - there is using not one jar-file, but it has a lot of dependencies in different directory levels on the same path. And second - if I place all libraries files in lib directory, grails Tomcat plug-in starts compile with errors. 
Actually, I need place gf-client.jar only in development mode. On real server all libraries are attached to server though catalina.properties